How to obtain bivariate regression coefficients from two univariate regression coefficients?
Let's assume that we want to obtain the coefficients of the following bivariate regression: $Y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_2 X_2 + \epsilon$
However, we don't have access to the data $(X_1,X_2,Y)$. The only information available are:

Coefficients of the univariate regression $Y=\gamma_0 + \gamma_1 X_1 +  \varepsilon$
Coefficients of the univariate regression $Y=\lambda_0 + \lambda_1 X_2 +  \nu$
Variances of $X_1$ and $X_2$, plus correlation between these two
Variance of $Y$

How can we obtain $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ from this information?

I’m voting to close this question because it is not specific to Quantitative Finance and belongs on Cross Validated Stack Exchange instead.

Betas are $(x'x)^{-1}(x'y)$. You know $(x'x)^{-1}$ from variances and correlation. You know $x'y$ from the correlation between each x and y (imply from regression coefficient).
Edit for clarity, x is a matrix of the data of the final regression.
Final edit: If you know the covariance matrix of x1,x2 and y, then you know the joint distribution completely and therefore you know the new coefficients completely. They are in this case, deterministic and one need not calculate the coefficients to realise this. This is ofc assuming normality

I spent some time trying to hash out the details of what you wrote above and was not able to compute the terms.  Could you provide more details on how you obtain the numerator and denominator. Then, coincidentally,, I  pointed to this question from cross validated because there was a similar question over there. Someone replied that above is incorrect but I'd like to know for sure. Thanks a lot for any details. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/644458/range-of-ols-regression-coefficient-when-combining-disjoint-datasets/644474#644474

@markleeds that is a different question that also cleaves y. What I've written is by definition correct, can you tell me where you were stuck?

Hi. The guy that claimed incorrect definitely read the question and answer and has a gigantic rating on cross validated. So, that's why I asked.  I got stuck calculating $x^{\prime } y$. Thanks for any details.

x'y becomes ([y_mean product(x1,y) product(x2,y)]/n) and covariances are known from the other regressions. WLOG means of each variable are 0 so products can be related to covariances. I am 100% confident that the OLS estimator can be written as the way I have, by every definition, it shouldn't be hard to google it.

@markleeds please see edit, would be happy to see someone generate multiple possibilities of the betas as was done in the link you pasted. Thanks!

We don't have $x_1, x_2$ or $y$ so if you can show how you get $\hat{x}_1$ or $\hat{x}_2$ or $\hat{y}$ (all three not necessary), that should tell me whether I'm going in the right direction. I'm sorry to spend your time and it's appreciated.

@markleeds actually you can't, you have 3 unknowns and 2 constraints (each regression line should pass through the mean).

arshdeep: the way you wrote $x^{\prime} y$ as a product,means that one needs to know $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ ( or atleast estimates of them ) in order to compute it. Unless I'm really missing something !!!! Let me know cause now I'm more confused than before. Thanks.

I'm sorry. Though you don't have data $x1'y$ is just beta in the first regression times Variance of $x1$. Same goes for $x2'y$. WLOG I'm assuming means are 0. Betas don't change when each variable is differenced to make it's mean 0.

I'm sorry Arshdeep. I got defeated by the sleep gods. Yes, for the numerator, I can see the idea of using coefficient value times the variance of the predictor to get the $x^{\prime} y$ terms. But, regarding $(x^{\prime} x)^{-1}$, we need the  off diagonal elements of $x^{\prime} x$  which is unknown because the individual regressions didn't include the other variable. Maybe you are making an independence assumption about  $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ ?

really, betas are real numbers and there arent any assumptions about them - off diagonal elements are covariances of x1 and x2 which OP knows, or means of x1's and x2's, which you don't really know unless you assume mean of y.

sounds like the answer is that it is not possible to calculate $x^{\prime} x$ which makes it not possible to answer the question.  If we knew $\bar{y}$,  then its possible ( because the $\bar{x}$ could be obtained ) but, as far as what the OP wrote, it's not available.  thanks for your help.
